# Are there no intersection points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, compactness

It is given that $A= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}: sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x} \} $. To prove whether the given set  A is compact or not

So if $x \in A \iff sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}$

which means $1/y  \in A \iff sin(y)=y$

and we know that the only fixed point of $sin$ is $0$ and as there exists no point, $x : 1/x=0$ and hence $A=\phi$ and hence $A$ is compact

ANOTHER ARGUMENT:

$sin(1/x)=1/x $ $\implies \exists $ a real number $1/x$ such that $sin(1/x)=1/x$ as we know the only fixed point of $sin$ is $0$ and hence $A$ is empty and hence compact

Are the both proofs correct? When I showed it to bing AI it said it looks wrong..

Comment: Both proofs are basically the same, and both proofs are right. Asking bing AI if a mathematical proof looks right is utterly pointless.

Comment: I'd argue on what the definition of $A$ even *is*. How do you check if $\sin(1/0) = 1/0$ after all?

Comment: For the moment, we are still massively better than AI at proof-verification (I don't include things like Lean in that statement)

Comment: @Jakobian - I fail to see that as a problem with the definition. Clearly it is not true that $\sin \frac 10 = \frac 10$ since neither side is defined. Thus $0 \notin A$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair If its undefined then it doesn't mean its not true, it means its undefined. I'm sorry but this is just abuse of notation, and I think no mathematician should write such things.

Comment: @Jakobian I claim there exists no $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ such that $1/x=0$ suppose there exists then multiplying both sides by $x$ we get $1=0$ which is absurd

Comment: @Jakobian so the correct definition of $A$ should be $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}: sin(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}\}$ isn't it?

Comment: @Jakobian - So something can be true without being defined? 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves Did gyre and gimble in the wabe; All mimsy were the borogoves, And the mome raths outgrabe.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that's irrelevant, what's relevant and what I was hinting at is that one shouldn't write things like that, and encouraging them to do so is harmful for their education in my opinion.

Comment: @Jakobian I understand your point... I think the mistake is mine... I will edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both proofs are correct. Bing AI is NOT a good way of verifying proofs, it does not understand maths. LLMs (Large Language Models) like Bing AI only understand the shape of sentences. It can generate sentences which look like sentences it has already seen. This can give it some information about truth. For example, it has likely seen a lot of sentences that say something like "the sky is blue", and few that say "the sky is red", so if you ask it what colour the sky is, it will correctly tell you blue. However, an incorrect maths proof looks a LOT like a correct maths proof, often just a single symbol off. If you prod it, you can get it to "prove" nonsense. For example, here is a dialogue I just had with ChatGPT:

> Me: prove that 2 is a multiplicative identity
>
> ChatGPT: To prove that 2 is a multiplicative identity, we need to show that for any real number (or any applicable number set) 'a', the following equation holds:
>
> a * 2 = a
>
> Let's proceed with the proof:
>
> Let 'a' be any real number.
>
> a * 2 = a
>
> We know that multiplication is a commutative operation, which means the order of multiplication does not matter. Therefore, we can rewrite the left side of the equation as:
>
> 2 * a = a
>
> Now, let's examine the right side of the equation. Since 'a' is a real number, we can use the distributive property of multiplication over addition:
>
> 2 * a = 1 * a + 1 * a
>
> Now, let's simplify the right side:
>
> 2 * a = a + a
>
> Since addition is also commutative, we can write this as:
>
> 2 * a = 2 * a
>
> Now, subtract 2 * a from both sides of the equation:
>
> 2 * a - 2 * a = 2 * a - 2 * a
>
> 0 = 0
>
> The equation is true, which means we have successfully shown that for any real number 'a', the equation holds true:
>
> 2 * a = a
>
> This demonstrates that the number 2 acts as a multiplicative identity, as it leaves any real number 'a' unchanged when multiplied by 2.

You will note that it looks an awful lot like a maths proof, with only the small downside of being totally nonsense. If you try to get maths help from an LLM, it WILL give you incorrect answers, and worse, it will make them look like correct answers, because LLMs fundamentally do not understand mathematics. Ask a human instead.

This whole rant also applies to subjects other than mathematics. LLMs do not know anything about anything, and should never be relied upon.

Comment: ... Yes.. understood brother...will never ask it to check the proof... Thanks